# How do I get CLion to run an install target

Tags: cmake, clion

I'm evaluating CLion 1.2.1 on an existing project which is already using  CMake. The project is made up of a few library modules and a single executable.

I have an install target which I use to collect the executable and a configuration file together in a bin folder for debugging:

```
...
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/)
install(FILES config.xml DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/)
```

When building on the command line I'd just run:

```
make install
```

which as expected builds the binaries and if successful then runs the above install commands.

My problem is that I can't get CLion to run the 'install' target. I expected to be able to create a new Run/Debug configuration but the Target: dropdown only contains those targets added using *add_executable()* and *add_library()*.

I also tried adding 'install' to the Build options in the Settings dialog. That however runs install for every target now including 'clean' which is not right.

Comment: Issue about this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-838

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As of [2018.1 EAP, build 181.3741.16](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2018/02/clion-2018-1-eap-clang-tidy-options-valgrind-on-wsl-cmake-install/), CLion supports running `cmake install` if your project defines install targets:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](https://d3nmt5vlzunoa1.cloudfront.net/clion/files/2018/02/cmake_install.gif))</sub>

---

**Original Answer:**

I don't think that CLion implements this feature yet. However, you can work around this limitation by adding a CMake *"custom target"* (using [`add_custom_target()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html)) that will execute the `make install` command:

```
add_custom_target(install_${PROJECT_NAME}
                  $(MAKE) install
                  DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME}
                  COMMENT "Installing ${PROJECT_NAME}")
```

Now, all you have to do is "build" the `install_YOUR_PROJECT_NAME` target from the "targets" menu in CLion.

**Update:**

A more cross-platform technique might be the following:

```
add_custom_target(install_${PROJECT_NAME}
                  "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}" --target install
                  DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME}
                  COMMENT "Installing ${PROJECT_NAME}")
```

Answer (score 1):

@maddouri 's comment already addresses your question. Alternatively, Under **Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake**, you can also set **Build Option** for Debug or Release build type to something like **-j 2 install**. With this setting, whenever CLion builds the code, it will install your targets, too!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the installation to automatically precede the launch, open the Run | Edit Configurations dialog, choose the desired Run/Debug configuration, press App general add in the Before launch section, and choose Install from the drop-down list:

[image: 1]